# Spring: how to initialise Bean A after load of Bean B is complete?

Tags: java, spring

I have a BeanA which whose constructor requires BeanB.
Once BeanB has been instantiated (and its properties set), I'd like to invoke BeanB.init()

Is there a way of doing this?

An alternative would be to have BeanB.init() invoked after all beans in the context have been created.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `init-method` in your `applicationContext.xml` in order to specify an init method. If you want a bean to instantiate after another, you can use `depends-on`, even though any `ref` element (in this example inside `constructor-args`) will implicitly place a dependency.

This would initialize firstly Bean B with an `init` method and, when finished, use it in as constructor argument to A.

```
<!-- Bean B -->
<bean id="beanB" 
    class="classB"
    init-method="init"
/>

<!-- Bean A -->
<bean id="beanA" 
    class="classA"
    init-method="anotherInit">
        <constructor-arg ref="beanB"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: +1 There shouldn't be a need to use depends-on since BeanA's constructor will take and instance of BeanB and therefore the depends-on is implicit. However, init-method is right on.

Comment: @JohnB Thank you, added comment regarding any `ref` element will place an implicit dependency.

Comment: So, the init method on A will only be called after B is instantiated and injected with all of its properties? Cool, that's just what I need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make BeanB implement [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html). The drawback of this is that you're creating a dependency between BeanB and Spring, which is not great.

I think a better approach would be to inject all the dependencies in the constructor and call init form it. In this way, you don't need to tie your class to Spring.